# Overlay png image and darken image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i make the image darken, then overlay a png image like [here](http://factorybox.devilcantburn.com/blog/)?

here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Effect</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2'></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://i25.lulzimg.com/7cd053.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be easier to help if you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the code straight out of the site for you to see how it's done. The + image doesn't show up as the path to the img file is unknown to me.

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/xbkK6/).

Comment: awesome! what if i had an image how would i insert it?

Comment: Thirtydot solved it! Just put the img in the `.hover a.link_blog` selector in CSS.

Comment: @thirty now that's more awesome! thanks guys! mWah! You guys are life savers.

Answer (score 4):

Put a black background-color on the image container and fade out the image on hover.

The jquery (for example) would look something like this:

```
$('.fadable-image').each(function(){
$(this).hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 250, 'swing');
},function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 250, 'swing');
});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Could also be done with CSS pseudo classes, but then without effects.